# Get Color of a pixel in Image With Linux (Debian)

Tags: linux, image, shell

I have an image with 1920x1080 resolution, and I want to know if it is possible to get the color of one pixel in HTML version with a shell command in Debian

Example:

```
getcolorpixel -x 1900 -y 1000 --source 1.png
```

should return something like `#232323`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you install `imagemagick` you can get the color with the following command:

```
convert image.png -format '%[pixel:p{75,20}]' info:-
```

where `75` and `20` coordinates of the pixel, and `image.png` is a path to image. Note that this will return colors in 'human readable' format, like 'white' or 'lightblue', but that can also be used in HTML.

Comment: Can you get the colors in hex format `#232323` as well?

Comment: For hex format
`convert image.png -format '#%[hex:u.p{75,20}]' info:-`